# How to install and run the reindent.py

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have downloaded the Reindent-0.1.0 and trying to use this for automated indention purpose.
I don't know how to install and run these commands and while I am trying to use this command
I am getting following error

command:

```
 C:\Python26\Scripts\Reindent-0.1.0>Python setup.py
 C:\Python26\Scripts\Reindent-0.1.0>Pyth
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
 from setuptools import setup
 ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I don't understand the setuptools, where it is and how to put inside

please note my folder files in Reindent-0.1.0

Reindent.egg-info
PKG-INFO
README
reindent
setup.cfg
setup.py

Also how can I run the commands for reindent, for an example, once after I installed the reindent, if I want to 
run dryrun command how I should write?

If I write like this, will it be correct ???

`C:\ProjFolder\ApplicationDevelopment\GUI>reindent -d Test.py`

some realtime example of `"-d (--dryrun)  Dry run and -r (--recurse) Recurse"` will be helpful!!

and where I should target the command file path, in dos

to my application running directory or C:\Python26\Scripts\Reindent-0.1.0 ?? OR  Application development folder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the error "no module X" when you try to run some code, that code has a dependency on module X. When you run setup.py and it says there is no module named "setuptools", it is telling you that setup.py requires the module "setuptools". Since you don't have "setuptools" installed on your machine, you get the error.

The fix is simple: install the setuptools module. Here's one of several places on the internet that shows you how to install setuptools: https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

Comment: @Brayan, It was a very good answer, really appriciate you for helping me.